# How to make letter spacing in verbatim/fancyvrb look like listings

Tags: spacing, listings, verbatim, fancyvrb

I've just noticed that the spacing between letters is different in `verbatim` vs. `lstlisting` environments:
[image: example of the difference in letter spacing]

Given that I add the option `columns=flexible` to the `lstlisting` environment, the spacing in this environment looks similar to the one in the `verbatim` environment. Is it possible to do the reverse, i.e. to make the text in the `verbatim` environment look like the text in the `lstlisting` environment (possibly using the fancyvrb package)?

Below is the sample code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
  Dummy code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{verbatim}
  Dummy code
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of the features of `listings` I like the less: letterspacing lowercase text is a capital sin. However, here's how you can do it (don't tell Frederic Goudy, please).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{microtype}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\verbatim@font{\lsstyle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
  Dummy code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{verbatim}
  Dummy code
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The small difference is due to the fact that letterspacing is applied only between letters. You may have also to increase the interword spacing.